# Is there a way to implement show hide divs in a responsive website?

Tags: responsive-design

Is there a way to implement show hide divs in a responsive website once the viewport contracts to say a width of 500px?

What I want to do is when the viewport contracts to the width of 500pixels each of the current divs can be hidden by show hide or a toggle or some kind of accordion?

What this means is that these functions do not "kick in" until the viewport contracts to this width.

Is this possible?

Here is the site I need to do this on:

http://surfingthebluemarble.com/mnews.html

Right now when this site contracts, the content is way too long. I need to hide to be able to hide and show those divs on click.

Thanks in advance for your help as always.

Regards,
umbre gachoong

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create `css` targeted to certain viewports (screens)

e.g.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Refer [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)